# How to make css notifications without jQuery?

Tags: css

Simply I just want to make a notification window that automatically hide after some time. but I don't want to use any jQuery in this.

any one having code ?

Comment: @hashem: Sir of course we are not here to write code for everyone but we can suggest some links, to them.

Comment: @skgacharya I don't hesitate to help but the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use my code to show notification.

```
    tn-box {
    width: 360px;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    right: 15px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0.9)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0.9);
    cursor: default;
}
```

and after that to hide the window use

```
.tn-box {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 5s linear forwards;
    -moz-animation: fadeOut 5s linear forwards;
    -o-animation: fadeOut 5s linear forwards;
    -ms-animation: fadeOut 5s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeOut 5s linear forwards;
}
```

Comment: Okey, this is working. sure I'll visit there.

Comment: this works, but to add class .tn-box there is still javascript required

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any javascript, you can use the animation property like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes alertHide {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        display: none;
    }
}

.alert {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    -webkit-animation-name: alertHide;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="alert">
    Alert Message
</div>
```

With `-webkit-animation-delay` you can define how long the message should be displayed.

Note: This code only works in Chrome/Safari. To get a broader browser support you need to enhance it with some browser prefixes (`-moz` etc.).

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sb08efu7/