# Verify Email address with valid MX SERVER

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, c#-4.0, email-validation

I'm working on a desktop application to send bulk email. Here I have to verify the email address is valid or not. using the Regex I can valid the format but how to verify the email address actually valid or hosted.

```
           string email = txtEmailAddress.Text.Trim();

            if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(email, @"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("XInValid email address!"); 
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Valid email address!"); 

            }
```

Now the question is still pending. how do I valid the email address? I google it but didn't get any useful link are some links are not free.

Comment: Why dont you just use email verification service and clean your email first. https://www.accuwebhosting.com/blog/top-10-bulk-email-list-verification-validation-services-compared/

Answer (score 2):

You may use email validation service like [mailcheck.co](https://mailcheck.co/?utm_source=inbound&utm_medium=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=recommend&utm_content=35939258) which has free quota and allows to make validation via curl. 
Also google have free api to receive MX records for domain - https://dns.google.com/query?name=nodeart.io
It allows to query not only MX records, but also an A records.
Correct flow is to resolve MX record - there will be not IP adress in it, but cname. After that you need to resolve that new address, and if there will be A record you finally will get ip address of MTA server. Unfortunately MX could rout to CNAME, which will route to another CNAME, which will route to A record. Small recursion. But you can stop on MX only.

Answer (score 0):

You can not verify if the email is 100% valid, unless you actually send it.

Indeed, you could check the MX record (or A record, if MX is not found) but, you can not verify, for example, if the user exists.

Here's a list of services which could help you : https://www.marketingtechblog.com/verify-email-lists/

Comment: You may have missread my answer...

And please, instead of waiting for a code sample, try to investigate with what you get ;)

Comment: I should have copy/paste your comment : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315399/how-to-make-css-notifications-without-jquery/29315634#comment46823550_29315399

Anyway, here's a code sample to check for MX record : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283103/finding-the-mx-record-using-c

Comment: I'm not getting your point about copy/paste and the link you provide... check the "dnsServers" that is not valid